# How to use Objective-C function with a block input in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, objective-c-blocks

I'm using a Objective-C SDK. The function I want to use take a parameter that
delegates the delegate for handling user consent

```
- (void) startWithDelegate: (id<SharingDelegate>) delegate;
```

The SharingDelegate requires me to implement 2 functions, one of them has a block input

```
(void) getUserConsent: (void (^)(BOOL)) consentHandler deviceN: (NSString *) deviceN;
```

Can anyone tell me how to implement this function in Swift? what is the signature?

Answer (score 0):

If it is a *method* (hard to tell because your display of it is garbled), I take it that it would be something like this:

```
func getUserConsent(consentHandler:Bool -> (), deviceN: String) {
    // body goes here
}
```

Comment: This function actually has 1 input, not 2

Comment: It has 2 parameters. Are you really displaying it accurately? Where are you getting all of this from, anyway?

Comment: If you think you already know the answer, why are you asking?

Comment: No. I don't know the answer. The SDK API states there is only 1 parameter

Comment: And it's not nice to vote down people's questions just because your answer is not what they are looking for.

Comment: Did you actually try it the way I suggested? Can you point me to the SDK API so I can see for myself? - (And please don't waste time and bandwidth commenting on downvotes; you don't know who downvotes you and you have no way of getting in contact with them.)

Comment: Hey @FishOnTray, I had an idea - I think you are misreading the API. Yes, the `consentHandler:` handler takes one parameter - and so does the function parameter in my Swift rendering. So that must be what they are talking about. But this method you are asking about clearly takes two parameters, the `consentHandler:` (a function taking one parameter) and the `deviceN:` (a string). So I think you'll find my answer is right.

Comment: I tried your answer, still get the error Type xxx does not conform to protocol

Comment: Well, as I said, it would help me to _see_ the actual declaration of this protocol in Objective-C or whatever it is you've got.